# So much crawling errors in Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console

[image: Desktop errors]

[image: smartphone errors]

most of these errors are due to the older pages that do not exists now..so there is no scope for them on my site now..pls help

Answer (score 0):

Broken links do hurt SEO a lot. But do not worry much about the old Webmaster Tools data. Do care more about current broken links in the website. Use some tools like [Xenu Broken Link checker](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) or Screamingfrog broken link checker to find. If any, fix it. That will enhance user experience better. Webmaster tool data generally be old and sometimes you can ignore some errors if it is not relevant. It will remove the data soon. But do check Webmaster Tool data often to notice the site improvements and errors.